# Parsing an Indexed Type

Tags: parsing, haskell, dependent-type, dynamic-typing

I just started exploring the possibilities of [data types à la carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) in combination with indexed types. My current experiment is a bit too large to include here, but can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jakubdaniel/6b67eb67b3bd7e2c284a5c68074ed7db). My example is mixing together an expression from different ingredients (arithmetic, functions, ...). The goal is to enforce only well-typed expressions. That is why an index is added to the expressions (the `Sort` type).

I can build expressions like:

```
-- define expressions over variables and arithmetic (+, *, numeric constants)
type Lia = IFix (VarF :+: ArithmeticF)

-- expression of integer type/sort
t :: Lia IntegralSort
t = var "c" .+. cnst 1
```

This is all good as long as I construct only fixed (static) expressions.

Is there a way to read an expression from string/other representation (that obviously has to encode the sort) and produce a dynamic value that gets represented by these functors?

For example, I would like to read `((c : Int) + (1 : Int))` and represent it somehow with `VarF` and `ArithmeticF`. Here I realize I cannot obtain a value of static type `Lia IntegralSort`. But suppose I have in addition:

```
data EqualityF a where
    Equals :: forall s. a s -> a s -> EqualityF a BoolSort
```

I could expect there being a function that can read `String` into `Maybe (IFix (EqualityF :+: VarF :+: ...))`. Such a function would attempt to build representations for the LHS and RHS and if the sorts matched it could produce a result of statically known type `IFix (EqualityF :+: ...) BoolSort`. The problem is that the representation of LHS (and RHS) has no fixed static sort. Is what I am trying to do impossible with this representation I chose?

Comment: "Here I realize I cannot obtain a value of static type Lia IntegralSort. " why not? It seems relatively straightforward to write a parser if the types are fixed. It becomes trickier if the output type depends on the input string, but it is still doable with existentials. `Data.Typeable` may help for your `Equals` example.

Comment: This is exactly what I am saying... I am interested in types that depend on input values, fixed types are obviously ok.

Comment: Looking at your language it appears that you'll need to do some unification. (eg in the expression `Select arr ix`, if you know the type of `arr` you can infer the type of `ix`.) Implementing a unification algorithm and proving it correct in the type system is fun, but maybe a bit too big for a stack overflow answer, especially in clunky old Haskell.

Comment: If fixed types are ok, that seems to contradict the fact that you "cannot obtain a value of static type `Lia IntegralSort`".

Comment: The direct answer to your question is to [use existential quantification in the return type of your type checking function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408943/parsing-and-the-use-of-gadts/33411022#33411022)

Comment: @Li-yaoXia poor wording on my side. Point was that I dont hope the code to guarrantee a **fixed type** simply because the input string **value** can be anything, i.e. by calling`parse :: String -> FixedType` I impose the requirement on the return type instead of having that derived based on the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.=.) :: EqualityF :<: f => IFix f s -> IFix f s -> IFix f BoolSort
(.=.) a b = inject (Equals a b)
```

You can use a GADT to hide the sort, allowing you to return values of sorts depending on the input. Pattern matching then allows you to recover the sort.

```
data Expr (f :: (Sort -> *) -> (Sort -> *)) where
  BoolExpr :: IFix f BoolSort -> Expr f
  IntExpr  :: IFix f IntegralSort -> Expr f
```

Here is a simplistic parser of postfix expressions involving `+` and `=`.

```
parse :: (EqualityF :<: f, ArithmeticF :<: f) => String -> [Expr f] -> Maybe (Expr f)

parse (c : s) stack | isDigit c =
  parse s (IntExpr (cnst (digitToInt c)) : stack)

parse ('+' : s) (IntExpr e1 : IntExpr e2 : stack) =
  parse s (IntExpr (e1 .+. e2) : stack)

parse ('=' : s) (IntExpr e1 : IntExpr e2 : stack) =
  parse s (BoolExpr (e1 .=. e2) : stack)

parse ('=' : s) (BoolExpr e1 : BoolExpr e2 : stack) =
  parse s (BoolExpr (e1 .=. e2) : stack)

parse [] [e] = Just e
parse _ _ = Nothing
```

You might not like the duplicate cases for `=`. A more general framework is `Typeable`, allowing you to just test for the type equalities you need.

```
data SomeExpr (f :: (Sort -> *) -> Sort -> *) where
  SomeExpr :: Typeable s => IFix f s -> SomeExpr f


parseSome :: forall f. (EqualityF :<: f, ArithmeticF :<: f) => String -> [SomeExpr f] -> Maybe (Expr f)

parseSome (c : s) stack | isDigit c =
  parseSome s (SomeExpr (cnst (digitToInt c)) : stack)

parseSome ('+' : s) (SomeExpr e1 : SomeExpr e2 : stack) = do
  e1 <- gcast e1
  e2 <- gcast e2
  parseSome s (SomeExpr (e1 .+. e2) : stack)

parseSome ('=' : s) (SomeExpr (e1 :: IFix f s1) : SomeExpr (e2 :: IFix f s2) : stack) = do
  Refl <- eqT :: Maybe (s1 :~: s2) 
  parseSome s (SomeExpr (e1 .=. e2) : stack)

parseSome [] [e] = Just e
parseSome _ _ = Nothing
```

---

#### Edit

To parse sorts, you want to track them at the type level. Again, use an existential type.

```
data SomeSort where
  SomeSort :: Typeable (s :: Sort) => proxy s -> SomeSort
```

You can construct the sort of arrays this way:

```
-- \i e -> array i e
arraySort :: SomeSort -> SomeSort -> SomeSort
arraySort (SomeSort (Proxy :: Proxy i)) (SomeSort (Proxy :: Proxy e)) =
  SomeSort (Proxy :: Proxy (ArraySort i e))
```

A potential problem with `Typeable` here is that it only allows you to test equality of types, when you may want only to check the head constructor: you can't ask "is this type an `ArraySort`?", but only "is this type equal to `ArraySort IntSort BoolSort`?" or some other full type.
In that case you need a GADT that reflects the structure of a sort.

```
-- "Singleton type"
data SSort (s :: Sort) where
  SIntSort :: SSort IntSort
  SBoolSort :: SSort BoolSort
  SArraySort :: SSort i -> SSort e -> SSort (ArraySort i e)

data SomeSort where
  SomeSort :: SSort s -> SomeSort

array :: SomeSort -> SomeSort -> SomeSort
array (SomeSort i) (SomeSort e) = SomeSort (SArraySort i e)
```

The `singleton` package provides various facilities for defining and working with these singleton types, though it may be overkill for your use case.

Comment: I was probably looking for the `Typeable` approach, hardwiring the type beats the extensibility of data types a la carte imho, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: The more I examine this answer the more I like it. However, I could still use some explanations. Assuming the `Typeable` approach, how would one parse e.g. `(a : (array int bool))` for example? I am trying to use `attoparsec` and can easily parse that string into `name :: String` and `sort :: Sort`, I have a hard time figuring how to build a `IFix f s` to be wrapped into `SomeExpr` that has the proper sort. As demonstrated, doing the same for `IntegralSort` and `BooleanSort` is straightforward.

Comment: You can track the sorts you parse at the type level with another GADT. `data SomeSort where SomeSort :: forall (s :: Sort). Typeable s => proxy s -> SomeSort`. So when you parse a sort, return a value of type `SomeSort`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I have `data SortProxy (s :: Sort)`, `data SomeSort`, but when my grammar matches the index sort and the element sort, I have two instances of `SomeSort` but I seem to run into errors when trying to merge the proxies with `SortProxy i -> SortProxy e -> SortProxy (ArraySort i e)` since `SomeSort` quantifies over `s`. Could you maybe put together an example of code that given two `SomeSort` produces `SomeSort` that holds `ArraySort` of the two given sorts? I would really appreciate it, typeable seems to be too cryptic for me (the doc does not explain much).

Comment: Thanks. Believe it or not, I tried almost exactly the same thing quite early on. What I didn't know was possible, however, was that you can give type signatures in pattern matches and further did not try using it with `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: @jakubdaniel, my personal experience suggests: 1. If I'm using any other type system extension, I'm almost certain to want `ScopedTypeVariables` to express what I need. 2. If I'm not using any other type system extension, I'm almost certain to want `ScopedTypeVariables` so I can write more type signatures to help me fix type errors when I goof up. 3. If I don't enable `ScopedTypeVariables`, I'm likely to end up getting confused when I expect an instance head type variable to be in scope where it's not. So most of the time, I just enable `ScopedTypeVariables` before I start writing anything.